error while converting zoned time into get_local_time using Howard Hinnant's date library
#include "date/tz.h"
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
using namespace date;
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
auto tz = locate_zone("America/New_York");
zoned_time zt{tz, local_days{November/7/2021} + 1h + 30min, choose::latest};
zt = zt.get_local_time();
cout << " local time Original time: " << zt << endl;
return 0;
}

I am facing error while converting zoned time to local time. Error is
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'date::ambiguous_local_time'
what():  2021-11-07 01:30:00 is ambiguous.  It could be
2021-11-07 01:30:00 EDT == 2021-11-07 05:30:00 UTC or
2021-11-07 01:30:00 EST == 2021-11-07 06:30:00 UTC

I understand that its dst end duration. But even after giving 'latest' or 'earliest' it gives same error
While this says that "ambiguous_local_time is thrown when one attempts to convert an ambiguous local_time to a sys_time without specifying choose::earliest or choose::latest."

It is this line that is throwing that exception:
zt = zt.get_local_time();

And this line is also not doing anything useful (except throwing the exception).  If you remove it, you will get the expected output.
Details:
This line:
zoned_time zt{tz, local_days{November/7/2021} + 1h + 30min, choose::latest};

does exactly what you intended.  It takes the local time, transforms it to sys_time, finds that transformation ambiguous, and chooses the second mapping to use.
This line:
zt = zt.get_local_time();

Extracts the local_time from zt by mapping its internal sys_time back to local_time.  Then the assignment attempts to do the reverse mapping back to sys_time.  It finds it ambiguous again, but this time there is no choose::latest to resolve the ambiguity.
If this were not an ambiguous situation, this line would be a no-op (except for wasted cpu cycles).
If one really wants to do this, and apply choose::latest, the syntax is more verbose:
zt = zoned_time{zt.get_time_zone(), zt.get_local_time(), choose::latest};

This is still a no-op though.
And actually this works too:
zt = {zt.get_time_zone(), zt.get_local_time(), choose::latest};

Update
Attempting to respond to the comment below, but I am not positive I am answering the question in the comment:
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;
    auto tz = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    zoned_time zt{tz, sys_seconds{}};
    for (local_seconds tp = local_days{November/7/2021} + 1h;
         tp <= local_days{November/7/2021} + 3h; tp += 1h)
    {
        zt = {zt.get_time_zone(), tp, choose::latest};
        cout << " local time: " << zt << endl;
    }
}

Output:
 local time: 2021-11-07 01:00:00 EST
 local time: 2021-11-07 02:00:00 EST
 local time: 2021-11-07 03:00:00 EST


I was wondering if you were going to see this question, shouldn't have doubted it.

@MarkRansom SO has watch tags. Apparently he has the datetime and chrono tags under watch.

What I am looking for to achieve is if 2021-11-07 01:30:00 EDT then it should return 2021-11-07 01:00:00 EST again as dst is ending at that time. If I provide 2021-11-07 02:00:00 America/newJersy it returns 2021-11-07 02:00:00 EST. I am expecting to return 2021-11-07 01:00:00 EST.  In my program i am getting input time as 2021-11-07 01:00:00, 2021-11-07 02:00:00, 2021-11-07 03:00:00 and so on in broken time format. Time is without timezone.

I've updated my answer.  Please let me know if this answers your question.  If not, please clarify.

Sorry for confusion I think I have wrongly framed it. As I said I am getting wall clock time which has no timezone or dst effect.

Glad to help.  But I can't see your code.  I recommend you either edit your question with more code, or open a new question with code.
